# Copy Data from Two different databases with FK relation

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, copy

So the situation is as follow:

I have **production DB** called **DB1** which has huge data, around 250 GB.
I have **Test DB** called **DB2** on my local machine which has the same schema as the production DB but only the first two tables are partially filled(**UUT_RESULT, STEP_RESULT**).

What I want:
Copy the only related data from the Production DB tables (**PROP_RESULT**) to my local DB table.

Very important note: I can copy the entire table, However, it's huge. That's why I only want to copy the data from **PROP_RESULT** table in the production DB which has relation to the already existed data in my local DB.

Note: Only UUT_RESULT and STEP_RESULT are partially filled in the Local DB, other tables are empty and I need to populate them and that's why I am posting this.

The following image will make is easier to understand

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be done with some ETL tool but
A manual way comes to mind:
 - just join the test tables together ( I'm guessing the join condition would be STEP_RESULT.UUT_RESULT = UUT_RESULT.ID) to get all the relevant keys.

```
SELECT a.ID 
FROM STEP_RESULT a join UUT_RESULT b 
on a.UUT_RESULT = b.ID
```

So lets say you get a 1000 values of b.ID. Then manually create a select which will have all the values returned from the TEST sql in an IN condition and run it on PROD:

```
SELECT * FROM PROP_RESULT WHERE STEP_RESULT IN ('ID1','ID2', ...)
```

Not sure how exporting data in MSSQL works but I'm guessing you could just save that select as a separate table and then just load it into your TEST environment

Comment: the JOIN (STEP_RESULT.UUT_RESULT = UUT_RESULT.ID) is true. however, it gives me the shared between the first two tables. How can I get the shared with prob table which is in different DB? I didn't get the second part of your answer. Could you please elaborate morre.

Comment: by that I mean you manually copy all the keys from the select in TEST, and create a select in PROD which you run there. I changed my answer slightly, hopefully it is more clear now